# Renaming the CSRF token header name with Spring Security

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am in reference to the following Spring Security documentation about [csrf configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html).

It seems the default header name for the csrf token is: **`X-CSRF-TOKEN`**

As explained in the documentation:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

It seems AngularJs uses the following header name: **`X-XSRF-TOKEN`**

1. How can I change the header name on the Spring security side?
2. Is this the best way to proceed?
3. Will it impact the CSRF protection on classic non-ajax form submits and specifically the XSRF parameter name?

Comment: Did you need to do anything else in Angular to make it work? I am using spring-security 3.2 with above configuration and still get "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create your own bean instance of `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository`, set the property `headerName` on this instance and pass a reference to this instance to CSRF configuration as `<security:csrf token-repository-ref="..." />`.  For example,

```
<bean id="csrfTokenRepository" class="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository">
    <property name="headerName" value="X-SECURITY" />
</bean>

<security:http>
    <security:csrf token-repository-ref="csrfTokenRepository" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: I am using spring-security 3.2 based on Java config, is there a way I can setHeaderName in HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository. I actually ended up creating my own CustomSessionCsrfTokenRepository, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Please ask this has a new question where I can put in the answer.

Comment: You may answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022967/using-angularjs-with-springsecurity3-2-for-csrf .I ended up creating a CustomCsrfTokenRepository just to override the header name.

Comment: Please check the combined answers in this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293303/renaming-spring-csrf-token-variable/37069462#37069462