# Using AngularJS with SpringSecurity3.2 for CSRF

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

**AngularJS**

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
</head>
```

**SpringSecurity 3.2**

Spring uses **HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository** which by default gives header name for CSRF as  **X-CSRF-TOKEN**, however Anuglar convention is  **X-XSRF-TOKEN**

I wanted to extend **HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository** and override the header name, but since it is marked final I ended up implementing a custom token repository.

```
@Component
public class CustomCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {

  public static final String CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME = "_csrf";

  public static final String CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

  private final Map<String, CsrfToken> tokenRepository = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

  public CustomCsrfTokenRepository() {
    log.info("Creating {}", CustomCsrfTokenRepository.class.getSimpleName());
  }

  @Override
  public CsrfToken generateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new DefaultCsrfToken(CSRF_HEADER_NAME, CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME, createNewToken());
  }

  @Override
  public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    String key = getKey(request);
    if (key == null)
      return;

    if (token == null) {
      tokenRepository.remove(key);
    } else {
      tokenRepository.put(key, token);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public CsrfToken loadToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String key = getKey(request);
    return key == null ? null : tokenRepository.get(key);
  }

  private String getKey(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getHeader("Authorization");
  }

  private String createNewToken() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private CustomCsrfTokenRepository customCsrfTokenRepository;


     @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
    //          .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/app/authentication")
                    .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                    .usernameParameter("j_username")
                    .passwordParameter("j_password")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()

                 .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(customCsrfTokenRepository)
                    .and()
              }
           }
```

1. How can I cleanly override the header name instead of creating a custom csrfTokenRepository?
2. Is there any other configuration changes I need to do for Single Page
   Applications such as AngularJS, as this does not work yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When using Java configuration for Spring Security, the following should be possible:

```
  public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    tokenRepository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");

    http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(tokenRepository);
  }
```

The complication is that single-page applications rely on AJAX and including CSRF tokens with AJAX requests is a bit complicated.  When using AngularJS, the server should send a session cookie called `XSRF-TOKEN` upon first request and whenever a user logs in or logs out.  AngularJS will then return the value of this cookie in the HTTP header `X-XSRF-TOKEN` with all requests, which the server can then check.

Comment: I am seeing people using filters to send cookie in response headers. Example https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/allanditzel/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter.java and as per spring docs "One might ask why the expected CsrfToken isn't stored in a cookie. This is because there are known exploits in which headers (i.e. specify the cookies) can be set by another domain". Do you have an example which shows that spring sends back CSRF token in  "Session Cookie"?

Comment: As you mentioned, Spring Security does not provide out-of-the-box support for setting CSRF token in a cookie.  Writing a filter is the best way.

Comment: Please check the combined answers in this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293303/renaming-spring-csrf-token-variable/37069462#37069462