# Renaming Spring csrf token variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

My application runs under another portal application. Both are implemented in spring and both use csrf security.

My need is basically change how the csrf token is named in the session, so both the tokens can work without conflicts. What I tried so far is creating another token repository and trying to change the parameter name and the session attribute name in the security config class.

```
final HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
tokenRepository.setHeaderName("TOOLBIZ-CSRF-TOKEN");
tokenRepository.setParameterName("toolbiz_csfr");
//tokenRepository.setSessionAttributeName("toolbiz_csrf");
```

When I make request Spring doesn't really like this new setup very much, and the log produces the following line:

```
Invalid CSRF token found
```

What should I do more? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:-

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class OptosoftWebfrontSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    repository.setParameterName("_csrf");
    return repository;
}

}
```

And the filter:-

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                .getName());
        if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie == null || token != null
                    && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Did you override the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#configure method?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember to delete any old cookies that you've got before renaming the Header. I had the same problem where everything was setup nicely, but old cookies in the browser caused the filter function to be useless basically.